# mvn clean install converting contents of properties file into different format

Tags: maven, maven-2

I have an issue while compiling the project using `mnv clean install`, its simply converting the contents of properties file into different format.

For example: `test_ja.properties` file having following key-value.

**Before Compilation**
    -> `exception.details=\u4F8B\u5916\u306E\u8A73\u7D30.`

**After Compilation**
     -> `exception.details=\u00004f8b\u00005916\u0000306e\u00008a73\u00007d30.`

I have tried and googled for same, but not getting any solution.
I am using `maven-compiler-plugin` `version - 3.2`

Here is code snippet of **pom.xml**

```
<profile>
<id>uat</id>            
<properties>
   <hostname></hostname>
</properties>   
<activation>
    <property>
        <name>env</name>
        <value>uat</value>
    </property>
</activation>
<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile-test1</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <propertyfile file="target\classes\test_ja.properties">
                                <entry key="toemail"
                                            value="test@test.com" />   </propertyfile>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>UAT</finalName>
</build>
</profile>
```

Comment: it is the maven-resources-plugin which is responsible for copying non-java files like your properties file. Seems to me you've activated filtering, in which case you might need to set the encoding.

Comment: No. there is no filtering applied.

Comment: Please try `mvn clean process-resources -X`and confirm you still see the issue. Also have a look at the debug logging if you see any hints. I'm not aware of a bug, but you could lock the maven-resources-plugin to 3.0.2.